# Scala case class copy with dynamic named parameter

Tags: scala

For scala case class with number of parameters (21!!)

e.g. `case class Car(type: String, brand: String, door: Int ....)`
where type = jeep, brand = toyota, door = 4 ....etc

And there is a copy method which allow override with named parameter: `Car.copy(brand = Kia)`
where would become type = jeep, brand = Kia, door = 2...etc

My question is, is there anyway I can provide the named parameter dynamically?

```
def copyCar(key: String, name: String) = {
  Car.copy("key" = "name") // this is something I make up and want to see if would work
}
```

Is scala reflection library could provide a help here?

The reason I am using copy method is that I don't want to repeat the 21 parameters assignment every time when I create a case class which only have 1 or 2 parameter changed.

Many Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why the `copy` command isn't already doing exactly what you need.  Why do you want to provide the parameter dynamically?

Comment: @RexKerr  I can see it: he gets a map of (name,value) pairs and then wants to invoke `Car.copy()` with it. Your way would have it all hardcoded to specific parameters.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I've just implemented a Java reflection version: [CaseClassCopy.scala](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/freshcode_public/learn_scala/syntax/src/main/scala/pckg_2_10/CaseClassCopy.scala).  I tried a [TypeTag version](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/freshcode_public/learn_scala/syntax/src/main/scala/pckg_2_10/CaseClassCopyTypeTag.scala) but it wasn't that useful; TypeTag was too restrictive for this purpose.

```
  def copy(o: AnyRef, vals: (String, Any)*) = {
    val copier = new Copier(o.getClass)
    copier(o, vals: _*)
  }

  /**
   * Utility class for providing copying of a designated case class with minimal overhead.
   */
  class Copier(cls: Class[_]) {
    private val ctor = cls.getConstructors.apply(0)
    private val getters = cls.getDeclaredFields
      .filter {
      f =>
        val m = f.getModifiers
        Modifier.isPrivate(m) && Modifier.isFinal(m) && !Modifier.isStatic(m)
    }
      .take(ctor.getParameterTypes.size)
      .map(f => cls.getMethod(f.getName))

    /**
     * A reflective, non-generic version of case class copying.
     */
    def apply[T](o: T, vals: (String, Any)*): T = {
      val byIx = vals.map {
        case (name, value) =>
          val ix = getters.indexWhere(_.getName == name)
          if (ix < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown field: " + name)
          (ix, value.asInstanceOf[Object])
      }.toMap

      val args = (0 until getters.size).map {
        i =>
          byIx.get(i)
            .getOrElse(getters(i).invoke(o))
      }
      ctor.newInstance(args: _*).asInstanceOf[T]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Here is a [slightly cleaned up version](https://gist.github.com/mslinn/a64b5152b2c035103a326d3f21ce2e79) that works with Scala 2.12

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using case classes.

Copy method generated at compile time and named parameters handled on compile time to. There is no possibility to do it ar runtime.

`Dynamic` may help to solve your issue: http://hacking-scala.tumblr.com/post/49051516694/introduction-to-type-dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need to use reflection to do that.

It is a bit involved, because `copy` is a synthetic method and you'll have to invoke the getters for all fields except the one you want to replace.

To give you an idea, the [copy method in this class](https://github.com/Sciss/GUIFlitz/blob/master/src/main/scala/de/sciss/guiflitz/impl/AutoViewImpl.scala#L311) does exactly that, except using an argument index instead of name. It calls the companion object's `apply` method, but the effect is the same.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a bit confused - how is the following not what you need?

```
car: Car = ...          // Retrieve an instance of Car somehow.
car.copy(type = "jeep") // Copied instance, only the type has been changed.
car.copy(door = 4)      // Copied instance, only the number of doors has changed.
// ...
```

Is it because you have a lot of parameters for the initial instance creation? In that case, can you not use default values?

```
case class Car(type: String = "Jeep", door: Int = 4, ...)
```

You seem to know about both these features and feel that they don't fit your need - could you explain why?

Comment: I think the OP's question is valid. In your example, "type" and "door" are hard-coded. What if you only know what key and value pair you would get at runtime?