# Scala case class copy constructor with dynamic fields

Tags: scala, immutability, setter, getter, case-class

I have an immutable `State`, and I process a message queue, where each message is a list of new values to some fields in the state.

The new values may apply to a part of a field - for example setting or clearing one flag (bit) out of many, or changing just the low or high 8-bit part of a 16-bit field.

After processing the message, I want to get an immutable copy of the state, with the modifications applied.

```
object StateField {
  sealed abstract class StateField()
  sealed abstract class Register extends StateField
  sealed abstract class Flag extends StateField
  case object AX extends Register
  case object AH extends Register
  case object AL extends Register
  case object CF extends Flag
  case object OF extends Flag
}

class StateFieldModification(field: StateField, value: Int)

class ModificationMessage(content: List[StateFieldModification])

case class State(AX: Int, Flags: Int) {

  def readRegister(field: StateField.Register): Int = field match {
    case StateField.AX => this.AX
    case StateField.AH => this.AX & 0xFF
    case StateField.AL => (this.AX << 8) & 0xFF
  }

  def readFlag(field: StateField.Flag): Boolean = field match {
    case StateField.CF => (this.Flags & 0x0001) != 0
    case StateField.OF => (this.Flags & 0x0800) != 0
  }

  def flagsWithBit(flagBit: Int, newBitValue: Boolean): Int = {
    if (newBitValue) Flags | (1 << flagBit) else Flags & ~(1 << flagBit)
  }

  def withModification(modification: StateFieldModification): State = modification.field match {
    case StateField.AX => this.copy(AX = modification.value)
    case StateField.AH => this.copy(AX = (this.AX & 0x00FF) | (modification.value << 8))
    case StateField.AL => this.copy(AX = (this.AX & 0xFF00) | modification.value)
    case StateField.CF => this.copy(Flags = flagsWithBit(1, modification.value > 0))
    case StateField.CF => this.copy(Flags = flagsWithBit(12, modification.value > 0))
  }

  def withModifications(message: ModificationMessage) = ???
}
```

**Q#1** - what's the best way to make a field getter based on a "field key"?

**Q#2** - what's the best way to make a field setter based on a "field key"?

**Q#3** - what's the best way to make a new object, given a mutability message?

Please note that:

- I'm experienced with Java but just starting with Scala.
- I'm doing a clean-sheet project, so you're more than welcome to comment about any part of the code, anything can be rewritten.
- The code above works, but it feels too far from what Scala elegance should look like.
- I *don't* want to use reflection, as suggested here:
  [Scala case class copy with dynamic named parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312254/scala-case-class-copy-with-dynamic-named-parameter)
- I *don't* want to use key-value map of fields instead of real class fields, like Python does.

All help appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: Why does `firstName` (for the sake of the example) have both a `String` and a case object representation?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov
In the `Person` class, there's a field `firstName` which holds the value.
In `PersonDetail` class, the `FirstName` is used as a key, saying which field we're talking about (could have been an Enumeration).

Comment: A thought about structure. The shape of the objects is being declared in two places - in the PersonDetail and again in the Person. This leads to needing to map between the two worlds - and there is no predefined way to do this. Defining the shape in only one place would sidestep some of the issues.

Comment: @FabFlying
Please note that `Person` defines the physical structure (first name and last name), but `PersonDetails` define the access interface to that structure (for example full name, which can be read and written, but is not a physical field).

Comment: I've rewritten the question so the use-case is more clear, please see now.

Comment: I think you'll need to either use reflection (or Lenses, see Alan's answer), or a key-value map rather than typed fields. There simply isn't any alternative. I think that Dima's answer is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lenses formalise the concept of having getter and non-mutating 'setter' functions for data structures, but we don't need the formalism to gain some of the advantages. We will use inversion of control to create modifier functions for your class. These modifier functions will encode ideas like:

- 'Give me the current state and a new AX, and I will give you a new state'
- 'Give me the current state and a function that calculates a new AX from the current AX, and I will give you a new state'
- 'Give me the current state and the new flags, and I will give you a new state'

So, the code:

```
case class State(ax: Int, flags: Int) {
  private def setAx(newAx: Int): State = copy(ax = newAx)
  private def modAx(f: Int => Int): State = setAx(f(ax))
  private def setFlags(newFlags: Int): State = copy(flags = newFlags)

  def withModification(modification: StateFieldModification): State =
    modification.field match {
      case StateField.AX => setAx(modification.value)
      case StateField.AH =>
        modAx { ax => (ax & 0x00FF) | (modification.value << 8) }

      case StateField.AL =>
        modAx { ax => (ax & 0xFF00) | modification.value }

      case StateField.CF =>
        setFlags(flagsWithBit(1, modification.value > 0))

      case StateField.CF =>
        setFlags(flagsWithBit(12, modification.value > 0))
    }

  def withModifications(message: ModificationMessage): State =
    message.content.foldLeft(this) { (state, modification) =>
      state withModification modification
    }
}
```

P.S., you can probably simplify some of your types, e.g. `StateField` doesn't really need to be a multi-level hierarchy--you can split it up into separate `Register` and `Flag` enums; and you can unwrap or type alias `ModificationMessage` since it's just a list.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be doing it all wrong. This would be an approach to take in a dynamic language like perl or ruby, but scala isn't like that. You can probably mimic something like that with scala, but it'll be hard enough to make you not want to.

`.getDetail` is not something you'll often see in scala. If you want to get a person's name, you'd usually just do `person.name` not, `person.getDetail(PersonDetail.Name)`. Why? Well, why not? There is simply no reason to do the latter when you can do the former.

Likewise for the setter: person.copy(firstName = "foo") works way better than `person.withModiciation(PersonDetail.Name, "foo")`

The third case is, perhaps, the most complicated. What if you wanted to apply a whole bunch of modifications? 
Well, I'll, still argue, that something like

```
val list = List(
  PersonDetail.FirstName -> "foo", 
  PersonDetail.LastName -> "bar", 
  PersonDetail.OtherStuff -> "baz"
) 
person.withModifications(list)
```

isn't any better than the scala's customary

```
person.copy(firstName = "foo", lastName = "bar", otherStuff = "baz")
```

Comment: If I'm writing my concrete code to access a field, then of course I'll use person.name.
But if I'm processing messages from an external source, and the message should contain a field identifier to retrieve, I need to represent that identified somehow, and be able to read the field that corresponds to it, right?

Comment: re person.copy - that accepts only constructor parameters.
so it will be fine with firstName and lastName, but I can't do person.copy(fullName = "foo bar") because there's no field called fullName in Person (nor should there be, as it's just a representation of other fields)

Comment: The point is that "to represent an identifier" (i.e. `"name" => PersonDetail.Name`)  is no different then to just use the data (`"name" => person.name`), only loner.  Re. changing the full name you can make a function to do that: `def withFullName(n: String) = { val Array(first, last) = n.split(" "); this.copy(firstName = first, lastName = last) }`

Comment: I want to separate the list of fields actually in Person (firstName and lastName), and list of fields which can be accessed in Person (such as fullName). I need the latter as an enumeration for another part of the code. So I need Person to have some sort of interface to read/write such a field.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am suggesting. The "list of fields actually in person" are the constructor parameters, the other fields - are just functions.: 
`case class Person(first: String, last: String) { def full = "%s %s".format(first, last) }`. And NO, you don't really need it as an enumeration.

Comment: I need the Enumeration for the message object. And I need to update Person given a message.

Comment: Send the object itself in the message, like I showed in the earlier comment, rather than a field, and data separately.

Comment: The message is like "change full name to X" or "change first letter of first name to Y". It doesn't know the state of the object.

Comment: Then make the fields optional: `case class Person(first: Option[String] = None, last: Option[String] = None) { def merge(p: Person) = copy(p.first.orElse(first), p.last.rElse(last) }`

Comment: If you mean to put fullName as an optional field of Person, it's something that I specifically want to avoid, because it would misrepresent what the object contains.

Comment: I addressed the fullName question in one of the earlier comments. Make a function for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127050/discussion-between-romi-kuntsman-and-dima).

Comment: I've rewritten the question so the use-case is more clear, please see now.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a Lens library [such as Monacle](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle)?  Lens are functional abstractions that allow you apply functions to part of a data structure, such as your Person case class.  A Lens allows you zoom in on part of the structure, so for Person, one could

```
import monocle.Lens
val firstName = Lens[Person, String]( p => f => p.copy(firstName = f))
val newPerson = firstName.set("someNewName")(person)
```

In this way each modification in PersonDetail could correspond to a suitable Lens.  Lens also support other operations too.  For more complex modifications, Lens can be composed as is shown on the Monacle README.  Besides calling a set function, they also can modify data based on a current value, to correspond to the FirstNameFirstLetter case.

```
firstName.headOption.modify(_.toUpper)(person)
```

Comment: I read about lenses, but I couldn't figure out about how they are on the one hand relevant for my use-case, but on the other hand not overkill.
Can you elaborate and give specific examples on how you'd implement my 3 questions using Lenses?